# SharePoint Licensing - Windows Server CAL needed in AD environment?

Tags: licensing

In a fully licensed Active Directory Environment (each user having his/her own PC running Windows 7). My question is not relating to the overall licensing but just about Windows Server User CALs.

Will I need a Windows Server User CAL per user for the SharePoint 2010/2013 server - what if I had three Frontend servers? Or will I only need a SharePoint User CAL? What about SQL Server Server CALs? Will I only need the Server CAL, licensed per server core - or also SQL User CALs?

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question. We have the same dilemma..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I undestood licensing now: The users don't need a separate Server User CAL as the users aren't accessing the servers themselves e.g. by RDP connection.

I also won't need SQL User CALs, only the Server CAL.